# Discount all products in stock in Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, discount, stock

I need to set a discount for all products that we have 1 or more pieces in stock. It seems there is no such condition in Magento shopping cart rules or catalog rules. Catalog price rule would be preferable so that customer could see the discount right at the product page.

I found and bought an extension that promises this feature as a bonus, but it's not working:

http://top-magento-extensions.com/magento-extensions/magento-discount-conditions-extension-week-scheduler-edition.html

Comment: if you want to give discount for `1 or more pieces in stock` means you want to give discount for all `in-stock` products, if you give dicount for all products, than that will be fine as because customer cant buy `out of stock` products......

Comment: @Baby there may be products that are set to in-stock but at quantity = 0 (e.g if back-orders are enabled)